# Finding a Number within a Column of number strings

Tags: excel, vba, string, excel-formula

Q: I want to find if a number is present within a string of numbers, if it is return the search number.

Example: I want to find a number in cell A1 within a column of string numbers within the column B. The search would need to be of a whole column as the data in cell A may not be next to the data

example: Cell A1: Will find an individual number such as 90075988

Cell B2: 217053 90069334 90069339 90069335 90069347 90069348 90069350 90075955 90075956 90075957 90075959 90075960 90075958 90075961 90075963 90075964 90075966 90075968 90075969 90075970 90075971 90075972 90075973 90075974 90075977 90075978 90075980 90075981 90075982 90075983 90075984 90075985 90075986 90075988 90075989 90075990 90075991 90075993 90075994 90075995 90075996 90075997 90076000 90076001 90076002 90076003 90076004 90076005 90076006 90076007

Cell B3: 482734 749732 1282354 515555 515560 90062311 90065999 90066000 90066007 90066008 90066006 90069420 90074773 90074774 90074775 90074776 90074777 90074778 90074779 90074780 90074781 90074782 90118115

Live example of data can be found here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13aX3t-r80Ap1mUxTGkjkh5kxbVaBjnrRpGauRvAExqM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Something like `=MID(B2,SEARCH($A$1,B2),LEN($A$1))` to search a single cell?  Or maybe `FIND` to search the whole column.  Does it appear in more than one string?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A1,B1,1)),A1,"")
```

Comment: Paste the formula and drag it down. Make chances if needed.

Comment: It doesn't work as the data in column A1 may not be in B1, it could be in B3 or b203